# SDC constraints for reusable component

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus, sdc

I have a simple register based clock divider component I can drop in when I don't have a spare PLL:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity div128 is
    port(
        inclk0 : in std_logic;
        locked : out std_logic;
        c0 : out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture syn of div128 is
begin
    div : process(inclk0) is
        variable counter : unsigned(6 downto 0);
    begin
        if(rising_edge(inclk0)) then
            counter := counter + 1;
            c0 <= counter(6);
        end if;
    end process;

    locked <= '1';
end architecture;
```

Now I'd like to reuse this component in multiple places, in different clock domains, without repeating myself more often than strictly necessary.

- Do I need to create a `create_generated_clock` statement for each instance, or can I specify once that each instance generates a `-divide_by 128` clock from its input?
- Could I also pull the divider from a `generic` parameter and take it over into the timing constraints?
- Would it make sense to use attributes here instead of an SDC file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify SDC commands inside of your VHDL code with ALTERA attributes. The PoC Library is using this to apply relative timing constraints for synchronizers:

```
architecture rtl of sync_Bits_Altera is
  attribute ALTERA_ATTRIBUTE  : string;

  -- Apply a SDC constraint to meta stable flip flop
  attribute ALTERA_ATTRIBUTE of rtl : architecture is "-name SDC_STATEMENT ""set_false_path -to [get_registers {*|sync_Bits_Altera:*|\gen:*:Data_meta}] """;
begin
```

Source: https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Bits_Altera.vhdl?ts=2

I think you could do a similar approach for your generated clock.

Please note, that `c0` does not fulfill all requirements to be a *clock* signal.

Comment: I'm getting a warning from TimeQuest that `c0` is not defined as a clock, even though it is used as one. It is probably not usable as a PLL input anymore (but neither is `coreclk_out` from the PCIe block, which is why I have so many clock domains in the first place.